# Passing multiple Include statements into a repository?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, linq-expressions

I am trying to figure out a way to pass a collection of include statements into my repository so that I can have it include specific entities. Below is some sample code from my repository.

```
   public TEntity GetById(Guid id)
        {
            return id != Guid.Empty ? GetSet().Find(id) : null;
        }
   private IDbSet<TEntity> GetSet()
            {
                return _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();
            }
```

The GetByID method calls the GetSet to return the entity set. I was thinking, if I could somehow pass in a collection of entities to include (via an expression) as part of my GetById, this way I wouldn't have to expose the GetSet to my services. So, something like this:

var entity = _repository.GetById(theId, e => {e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3});

I could then pass that expression into my GetSet method and pass it into an include statement. Thoughts?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have done something like this in my code recently. Would the following work for you?

```
public TEntity GetById(Guid id, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty) return null;

        var set = _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();
        foreach(var includeProperty in includeProperties)
        {
             set.Include(includeProperty);
        }
        return set.First(i => i.Id == id);
    }
```

Then you would call it like this...

`var entity = _repository.GetById(theId, e => e.Prop1, e=> e.Prop2, e=> e.Prop3);`

I know this doesn't exactly follow your pattern, but I think you could refactor it as required.

Comment: @Paige: I tried using this code, but when I traced the SQL none of the includes were actually added (but lazy-loading could give the illusion they were).  But if I hard coded the same includes into one line **var set = _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>().Include(includeProperties[0]);** then the include appeared in the SQL.  So looks like some difference in type, when composing the Includes separately, which I haven't got to the bottom of yet.

Comment: Got it working now - needed a couple of changes to the code.  I've added a new answer with the code I used.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think Paige Cook's code will work quite as shown.

I've included a modified version of the code that should work instead:

```
public TEntity GetById(Guid id, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    if (id == Guid.Empty) return null;

    IQueryable<TEntity> set = _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();

    foreach(var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
         set = set.Include(includeProperty);
    }
    return set.First(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

I only spotted this by tracing the SQL generated by Entity Framework, and realised the original code was only giving the illusion of working, by using lazy-loading to populate the entities specified for inclusion.

There's actually a more terse syntax for [applying the Include statements using the LINQ Aggregate method](http://appetere.com/post/Passing-Include-statements-into-a-Repository), which is in the blog post linked to.  My post also improves the method slightly by having a fall-back to the Find method, when no includes are needed and also shows an example of how to implement a "GetAll" method, using similar syntax.

Comment: Steve, I do not see how this is different than my answer? The code looks identical to me. And your GetAll method is missing. Are you sure you posted the correct code snippet?

Comment: @PaigeCook There are two differences.  First, you have to use the return value of the Include statement.  The original code just says **set.Include(includeProperty);** but I think this has to be **set = set.Include(includeProperty);**.  The second change is that I found I had to explicitly declare "set" as type IQueryable<TEntity>, rather than using "var".  With your original code, did you trace the SQL - if it worked I'm intrigued!  The last paragraph in my post was describing what was in my blog-post, which includes the GetAll method & terser LINQ version.

Comment: For anyone looking for the updated link to the blog post referenced for the 'terse syntax'
http://appetere.com/post/passing-include-statements-into-a-repository

Comment: Fixed the link in the post (and sorted my redirects for anyone who's bookmarked the original link).  Thanks @Patrick for alerting me.

Answer (score 1):

It's bad idea to store context in non-local space, for many reasons.

I modify Steve's code and get this for my ASP.NET MVC projects:

```
public aspnet_User FirstElement(Func<aspnet_User, bool> predicate = null, params Expression<Func<aspnet_User, object>>[] includes)
    {
        aspnet_User result;
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var set = context.Users.AsQueryable();

                for (int i = 0; i < includes.Count(); i++ )
                    set = set.Include(includes[i]);

                if (predicate != null)
                    result = set.ToList().FirstOrDefault(predicate);
                else
                    result = set.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch
            {
                result = null;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The include method can be strung together in your linq query like so:

```
var result = (from i in dbContext.TableName.Include("RelationProperty")
                                           .Include("RelationProperty")
                                           .Include("RelationProperty")
                select i);
```

Comment: I understand that, but this doesn't answer my question. In my service layer I want to pass, to the repository, what could be included without actually writing the chained includes in my service layer. Then I could pass that into some sort of include builder?

Comment: i'm not sure if it would work, but you could pass a collection of strings, which would be relational properties, then loop through them building on your IQueryable<T>

Comment: It thought about that. I am going to try that and update my questions. Another options is to extend the Include method?