# Calling DbContext.Set<T>().Include() is not querying the included properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have turned off lazy loading and the proxy creation on my DbContext. I am employing the Repository partern and UnitOfWork. My UnitOfWork inherits from DBConext. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
public class User
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public virtual Guid UserTypeId {get;set;} //foreign key to UserType and setup in the EF fluent mappings and it does load if I am using lazy loading.
     public virtual UserType {get;set;}
}

public class UserType
{
     public Guid Id {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

This is inside my UoW:

```
        public IDbSet<TEntity> CreateSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
        }
```

I query the context via my Repository:

```
 protected Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] Includes;
 public IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria, params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
        {
            Includes = includes;
            return GetSet().Where(criteria)
                            .AsEnumerable();
        }

    public IDbSet<TEntity> GetSet()
            {
                var set = _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();

                if(Includes != null)
                {
                    foreach (var include in Includes)
                    {
                        set.Include(include);
                    }
                }

                return set;

            }
```

So, as you can see I am passing in an array of expressions to be included in my query. So I might call it like this:

```
var users = userRespository.Get(u => u.Id == SomeGuid, u => u.UserType);
```

The UserType is not being included in the query and I don't know what. Should I be calling something other than Set on the DbContext?

**Update**:

I am thinking before I call the base.Set I would need to add the includes there. Not sure though.

Comment: What happens if you use: `set = set.Include(include);`?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, never thought about that.....I'll try it out...

Comment: @LadislavMrnka, if you want to make that the answer, I'll give you credit for it. That works PERFECT!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All extensions methods on `IQueryable` usually works in the way that they produce a new `IQueryable` so you must assign it if you want to get the effect:

```
public IDbSet<TEntity> GetSet()
{
    var set = _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();

    if(Includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in Includes)
        {
            set = set.Include(include);
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

Btw. it looks quite similar to [my older solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376421/ef-including-other-entities-generic-repository-pattern/5376637#5376637).

Comment: I wish I would have seen that when I started experiementing with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207048/passing-multiple-include-statements-into-a-repository